# Creating model with default fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I Have this Vehicle Model and I want to have some default values for my field when I first create the object and add it to the database. The problem is that this constructor is being called several times, not just in the creation of the Vehicle object. 
What am I doing wrong? Should I use another method to create models with default fields?

```
public class Vehicle
{
    [Key]
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }

    public bool Validated { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

    public Vehicle()
    {
        this.CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
        this.Validated = false;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Every time I call db.Vehicles.Find(id); it seems to me that Vehicle constructor is called, which is not what I want. I only want constructor to be called the first time object is created in the system, before being inserted to the database

```
// GET: Vehicles/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Vehicle vehicle = db.Vehicles.Find(id);
        if (vehicle == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(vehicle);
    }
```

Comment: The constructor will only be called once when an object is initialised.  If you are seeing it being called multiple times, that is because multiple objects are being created.

Comment: I only want to define the default fields when object is created for the first time, before being inserted in the database. When I get it from the database after creation, I don't want the constructor to be called.

Comment: A constructor will *always* be called when an object is created, no matter how it is created.  If you don't want default values, then don't put them in the constructor.  There are other options (non-default constructor, object initialisation etc).

Comment: What's the actual problem you're observing when you say the constructor is called multiple times? *Is* there an observable problem here?

Comment: "Every time I call `db.Vehicles.Find(id);` it seems to me that Vehicle constructor is called", yes, that's how C# (and most OOP languages) work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the initialisation then you could do something like this:

```
var myVehicle = new Vehicle
{ 
   CreationTime = DateTime.Now,
   Validated = false,
};
```

The default constructor (either the auto-generated one, or one you have written), will always be called, but if it does 'nothing', then when EF creates one, it will not impact anything.

Comment: He's saying he doesn't want `DbContext.Find` to call his constructor.

Comment: `DbContext.Find` will always call the default constructor.  If he hasn't declared one (or it is empty), then it doesn't do anything, so shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yeah I agree, I'm just wondering if his issue is bigger than his original question indicates.

Comment: This is what I wanted, tanks a lot. I'm sorry, I'm just now learning how to use the framework.

Comment: Just be careful if you use this approach - You're fighting against how EF and C# work. Maybe more importantly, you're going to to have to make sure you don't create instances of `Vehicle` from more than one location in your code - it could cause you problems if you decide to change the defaults, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your update seems to imply you don't want the constructor to get invoked, which I don't think you'll be able to avoid.

> When EF Core creates instances of these types, such as for the results
>   of a query, **it will first call the default parameterless constructor**
>   and then set each property to the value from the database. However, if
>   EF Core finds a parameterized constructor with parameter names and
>   types that match those of mapped properties, then it will instead call
>   the parameterized constructor with values for those properties and
>   will not set each property explicitly.

Comment: And, in reality, this provides nothing more than syntactic sugar over the constructor version.

Comment: @Neil, or are you saying this compiles in IL the way he had it before?  That I definitely didn't know.

Comment: I haven't checked the IL, but the outcome is identical.  It's possible one way is slightly more efficient that the other, but I bet there isn't much in it.

Comment: @Neil wow guess what, it definitely does compile exactly the same.  The only difference is when using default property syntax, it also adds a call to `base..ctor()`.  Very cool stuff.